# How to turn my Linux netbook into WiFi AP

Tags: linux, fedora, wireless-access-point, tethering

I'm trying find out how to make a linux ([Fuduntu](http://www.fuduntu.org/)) netbook with two network interfaces a wireless access point and act as router and share internet connection for a WiFi tablet.

- one interface is connected to `inet`, `eth0` (wired),
- other `eth1` is WiFi

So the question is some sort of tethering

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to turn an old notebook into a wireless AP. I don't know Fuduntu. I
use Debian, therefore the following instructions are Debian centric but can
easily be adapted to other distributions as well. What differs are the
package names and the location of the configuration files.

### Required software

The following packages are needed:

- hostap
- wpasupplicant
- bridge-utils
- wireless-tools

### Configuration

In the following it is assumed that your wireless connection is `wlan0` and
your wired one `eth0`, you need to adapt it to your setup.

First you need to set up the bridge. Remove or comment out any entries that
set up `wlan0` or `eth0` in the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the
following lines.

#### Setting up the bridge

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
  pre-up ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up
  pre-up ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0 up
  pre-up brctl addbr br0
  pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0
  post-down ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0 down
  post-down ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 down
  post-down brctl delif br0 eth0
  post-down brctl delbr br0
```

#### Setting up hostapd

Tell the `hostapd` daemon to use a particular configuration file: Ensure the
following line is present in  `/etc/default/hostapd`

```
DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Now you can set up your wireless network. Here I just provide an example
configuration. The exact values depend on your hardware, which encryption is
supported and your environment (e.g. surrounding networks). Open the file
`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` and ensure the following values are set.

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=MyNetwork
hw_mode=g
channel=9
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=myverysecretpassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Important here is to select a driver that works with hostapd and your
hardware. The SSID is a random string to identify your network. The channel
should be picked, so that there is the least interference with the surrounding
networks. The passphrase should be at least eight characters long.

For the other options read the provided configuration file. It is heavily
commented and almost serves as a manual.

### Starting the access point

Now you can bring up the interfaces

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and start the access point

```
/etc/init.d/hostapd start
```

### Another possible solution

The FreeBSD distribution [pfSense](http://pfsense.org/) is a firewalling and routing platform with AP functionality. Everything can be set up nicely using a GUI. Behind the scenes it also uses `hostap`, but the configuration is simpler and more user friendly. The drawback of using pfSense is that you should not do your regular computing on the same box, pfSense expects to be running on a dedicated system, although this is not a technical requirement.

Comment: Actually, if you don't like the idea of writing a configuration file for `hostapd`, the popular NetworkManager tool also supports managing an AP now, but this is not available through its GUI tools; it requires a manual tweak in its configuration file for `mode=ap`. Reference in Russian: http://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.B0_.D0.B2_NetworkManager

Answer (score 2):

If it's for your one and only tablet, an adhoc connection would be enough. You can use iptables to forward the traffic.

For other purposes, check if `hostap` works with your adapter, then you have a real access point for multiple users (use iptables for forwarding too here).

Comment: the ad hoc connection was the first i tryed. It is very ease in fuduntu (think in ubuntu the same) one click in network manager applet  in system tray and "make new wireless..." so i did a adhoc spot. But my tablet as **many** others  android tablet doesnt list ad-hoc spot! It wants only full feathured wifi Acces Point. my old half-wrecked windows mobile device can easily connect adhoc infrastructure and new android cant! Cést la vie. So the question is root out the tablet or make the AP infrastructure.