# Setting up a hotspot with hostapd

Tags: fedora, broadcom, hostapd

I've been using the steps described here to set up a wireless hotspot:

[How to turn my Linux netbook into WiFi AP](https://superuser.com/questions/437137/how-to-turn-my-linux-netbook-into-wifi-ap)

But when I type:

```
/etc/init.d/hostapd start
```

on the commande line, I get the reply

```
Starting hostapd: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.confnl80211 not found.
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
```

First this error is very strange ("/etc/hostapd/hostapd.confnl80211 not found", I'm not doing a typo here, this is a real error).

But is there something I'm doing wrong? What can I do so that the driver initialization cease to fail?

I'm on Fedora, using a Broadcom wireless card, and I can access to internet with it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The real error is `nl80211 not found.` The init.d script omitted the linebreak after `Starting hostapd: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` because it expected to print `...done` in the same line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I thought but I was not sure. Any idea on how to avoid this error?